# WordPress - Non Custom Metabox Custom Columns Sortable

Tags: wordpress, admin, jquery-ui-sortable

I have edited the default admin "Users" column to have two custom columns, "Number of Transactions" and "Latest Transaction" from a custom post type I created. I did not want to have the data that populates these columns as custom meta box fields as this seemed to create unnecessary options for the user and I did not want the user to be able to edit these fields.

After adding the columns I populated them with custom queries such as:

```
function test_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $userID =  $user->id;

    $query_for_number_of_transactions = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
                SELECT COUNT(post_author) AS number_of_transactions FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='club_orders' AND post_author=$userID;
            "
    );

    $query_for_latest_transaction = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
                SELECT DATE_FORMAT((MAX(post_date)), '%M %e %Y') AS latest_transaction FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='club_orders' AND post_author=$userID;
            "
    );

    // Display the query data into custom columns

    $er_qm_number_query_result = $query_for_number_of_transactions[0];
    $er_qm_transaction_query_result = $query_for_latest_transaction [0];

    switch($column_name){
        case 'latest_transaction':
            return $er_qm_transaction_query_result->latest_transaction;
            break;
        case 'number_of_transactions':
            return $er_qm_number_query_result->number_of_transactions;
            break;
        default:
    }
    return "Error";

    }

    add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'test_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

The above code works and displays the data I want to display in these columns. However, the issue I am running into is when I try to make either column sortable. I am finding a lot of material from Google searches pertaining to making custom columns populated by custom meta box fields sortable, but nothing on how to make a custom query populated columns sortable.

Is this even possible or do I have to create custom meta boxes and somehow make them read-only in order to sort this data?

Comment: If I understood correctly, your looking for [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/27518/12615). Enable sorting is easy, the problem is to do the sort itself. Oh, yes, Custom Field is one thing, Custom Meta Box is another. They can be used together, but a meta box can have other things than custom fields.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I mentioned that I did not directly create custom meta boxes for the data populating my custom columns and populated it with queries to existing meta information that creates new data based on existing meta data(view the queries). I do not want to have to create a custom field or meta box to store this information unless absolutely necessary. I cannot use the example you provided because it is referencing a meta key that I do not have(as the data in the columns is generated dynamically)

Comment: Your Q is not clear at all. You posted pieces of code without context. Where are they happening, which hooks? And, as I said, **`CF != MB`**

Comment: Added the rest of the function and the filter. Also, I am pretty sure this is neither "CF" or "MB", the query does reference existing metadata, but returns the new data that populates the columns.

Comment: Did you ever work this out @Eric? I am facing a similar problem now http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152494/make-a-custom-column-sortable-by-custom-post-count